# How can I schedule an e-mail in GMail using thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap, scheduling

GMail has the magical "Send later" feature which allows for scheduling e-mails.

Is there a way of scheduling an e-mail through Thunderbird, using GMail's service, so that I can prepare e-mails in Thunderbird and then let GMail send it on a given date even though I'll power off my PC?

Tried using IMAP folders but the Scheduled folder won't appear there. Copying them to Drafts also doesn't work, as I have multiple e-mails with same title, which appear in GMail as one e-mail without body and I'm unable to send that.

Comment: Ask on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Thunderbird&format=guided) for this to get implemented. Thunderbird is currently being considerably updated, so now might be a good time, before the new version also gets entrenched in a lack of support for this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to write your e-mail in Thunderbird, save it (so it gets to Drafts on Gmail), and then, in Gmail Web, run Send Later on the draft.

This way you can use all Thunderbird functions to prepare your e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can see to what you want is to add the [Send Later](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/) extension to Thunderbird which gives you scheduling ability within Thunderbird.

Thunderbird is constrained to only use the IMAP feature set, described briefly at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol and in detail in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6 and in neither place is there a command documented which will do exactly what you want.

Comment: But this doesn't solve my use-case. I want Thunderbird to schedule them in GMail, so that GMail sends them rather than Thunderbird

Comment: You may find an answer quicker at http://webapps.stackexchange.com, for someone may know of an experimental extension to IMAP (AKA an X-command); see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.5.1